# Serving static content from a Rails app, hosted outside of the Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, content-management-system

I have a Rails app that has a combination of dynamic and static pages.  For the static pages, I want to make them accessible for editing by my partner, who is not a Rails developer, and therefore wouldn't want to be going into git and making changes directly in the repo.

So, some sort of CMS seems like the right answer.

But for maintenance reasons - mostly related to difficulties upgrading the CMS gem that I've used in the past, I don't want to host a CMS inside of the Rails app anymore.  I also want to gain other benefits, like better editing tools and easier access to templates that come with a hosted CMS solution.

I was thinking that I could do something like host the static content on something like Wordpress or Squarespace, then somehow serve that static content from the Rails app.  If I used separate subdomains, I think this could be easy, but I'd like to keep all content under one `www` subdomain.

The Rails app is currently hosted on Heroku, and I use Google Domains for DNS.

I hope it is clear what I'm trying to achieve and why.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how this could be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with nginx reverse proxy in front of your app - you can proxy different paths to different apps/hosts like:

```
server {
   server_name your_main_host.com;

   # other nginx vhost config..

   location /cms_prefix/ {
      proxy_set_header Host host_that_cms_expects.com;
      proxy_pass http://your_cms_host.url/;
   }

   location / {
      proxy_set_header Host your_main_host.com;
      proxy_pass http://your_rails_upstream;
   }
}
```

Haven't deployed this method to heroku, but this should be possible by using [nginx buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nginx) in "solo mode" (actually you want "proxy mode" but with custom config)